# Prestashop - Erro no formulário - Estado - id_state - Sempre inválido

Tags: php, e-commerce

Estou com um erro que retorna o estádo como inválido, por que não carrega os estados do país e não consigo editar que nada acontece.

É o seguinte, ao cadastrar um Endereço,

O Estado, sempre carrega o nome do país, como única opção

Eu não consigo submeter por que dá erro que tenho que preencher um estado válido,

Se eu Inspeciono o elemento e coloco o id de um estado válido, passa e cadastra tudo certo.

Já tentei editar os arquivos addres.tpl, addresses.tpl, e order-opc-new-account.tpl e também o order-opc-new-account-advanced.tpl colocando manualmente os options dentro do select preenchendo cada estado do brasil e o id correto, mas não carrega no site nunca, parece que toda edição que faço é invalida.

Como são muitos, eu coloquei do lado do asterisco de campo obrigatorio, uma letra para cada um select de estado que tinha lá, e não aparece letra nenhuma, como se eu estivesse no arquivo errado.

To usando a ultima versão do prestashop 1.6 e o tema do Appollo AP FREE deste endereço:

http://apollotheme.com/products/category/free-prestashop-themes/

Segue endereço da minha loja com o erro:

http://b2b.cellsystem.com.br/endereco

Atualmente , está funcionando sem o campo de estado por que fui no banco de dados e coloquei que o brasil não tem estados ............. mas isso tá errado, preciso dos estados, não precisa puxar do banco, pode ser um select definido no html.....

Comment: Não deu pra dar upload aqui, entao dei upload lá no forum da prestashop dos arquivos:

https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/522983-preciso-de-suporte-iniciante-erro-no-formul%C3%A1rio-estado-id-state-sempre-inv%C3%A1lido/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boas, estava com o mesmo problema.

SOLUÇÃO:
Substituir themes/ap_office/js/tools/statesManagement.js
por themes/default-bootstrap/js/tools/statesManagement.js

Limpara cache Prestashop, recompilar e limpar cache do browser.